# Better Quantitative Measure of Predictor "Relevance" than p-values?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, aic, r-squared

I have a regression of the general form:

$$ Y = \alpha + \beta_{1}*X_{1} + \beta_{2}*X_{2} +\beta_{3}*X_{3} + ... +  \epsilon
$$

Let's assume the following constraints: k=14; all X's are standardized; and

$$\sum_{i=1}^{k} \beta_{i} = 1
$$

$$\beta_{i} \geq 0$$

I would like to efficiently measure the "relevance" of each regressor. At first I thought of using the p-value, but I realized for my purposes, that if... $\beta_{1} = 0.001$ with a p-value of 1E-5 it has a "relevant" p-value, but a relatively "irrelevant" $\beta$ because $\beta_{1} \ll 1/14$.

I could simply run 14 additional regressions, each with a different "missing" $\beta_i$ and compare R^2 to the original regression, $\Delta(R^2)_i$. I wouldn't tend to compare adjusted R^2 because each "side" model has 13 predictors versus 14 predictors in the "main" model. If I chose to compare $\Delta AIC$, I suppose I would have to adjust the 13-parameter AIC by adding $2*\Delta k$, or 2.

Let all $q_{i}$ each represent the "relevance" of each regressor. (Preferably each $q_{i}$ would be in the range [0,1], but that is just a convenience). Any better ideas than $\Delta(R^2)$?

P.S. I am **not** looking to use the $q_{i}$'s for model selection, though I suppose they could be used for that purpose.

Comment: I am thinking something like: $$q_{i} = (k*\beta_{i})^b/(1 - \sqrt[a]{pval_{i}})$$ where a=7, b=0.7.  These will not all fall in the range [0,1], but it would not be hard to map them to do so.

Answer (score 0):

In hypothesis testing "significance" means: the probability of observing the effect by chance, and does not refer to the effect size. It could be that there is a very small effect (a unit change in X is associated with a small change in Y), but that such effect is significant.

As for the constraint note that it is testable: you can start by estimating the unconstrained model, and test for the constraint (such test is implemented in most statistical softwares). Also note that an unconstrained least square estimator is less efficient but still consistent: if it's true that true betas sum to one, with enough observations so will your estimates.

Comment: Agreed!  I globally changed "significant" to "relevant", because "significant" does have a very specific statistical meaning.  I'm hoping the more general term "relevant" does not have a well-defined meaning and relates more to the common English definition I am trying communicate.  Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to test what coefficients are most relevant? since they're standardized, why not just consider the estimates (beta) themselves?

Comment: In some cases that serves my goal, but I am concerned about multi-collinearity and VIF. If X1 and X2 are highly correlated to each other and to Y, beta1 could be very low and beta2 could be very high simply because X2 is a _slightly_ better predictor. But a regression with X2 excluded would quite likely result in a large beta1. Thus, in my application, X1 and X2 are both "highly relevant."  Using just the betas would neglect X1 in this instance.  My idea of delta R^2 has presents the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at these for some suggestions:

http://jee3.web.rice.edu/riskstats.pdf
http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/ajps.12149/abstract

Comment: Also this: http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/ajps.12102/abstract

Comment: maybe you can expand you answer to include the suggestions form the links you provided?